# MYSQL sending notifications to multiple users

Tags: php, mysql

I want each time a new lesson is added to the `lessons` table, a notification send to all students in that grade. Let's say I have 10,000 students in the fifth grade, that means a 10,000 insert operations will be made in the `notifications` table which is a huge load.

Is there a better idea on how to send notifications to users, knowing that a user can see the notification only ONCE.

Comment: if 10,000 db operations is a huge load for your db, then I suggest upgrading your db and/or db server. 10,000 queries is **NOTHING** for a modern computer with a decent relational DB system running on it.

Comment: @MarcB I'm just assuming, how about 1,000,000 ? or more? I'm looking for a better idea for handling such cases.

Comment: You can look at cloud solutions, such as http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/

Comment: If there needs to be record creation, it will have to be done. Doesn't need to by done _at that very moment_ though. You can perfectly keep track of new lessons, and add the notifications in some asynchronous, possibly even staggered, cron-job / deamon / whatever.

Comment: Premature optimization is a certain way to slow application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the notification process can be made asynchronously.

I suggest to develop a separate message queue architecture for this scenario. A program will loads newly added data and put them in  a queue, then another process can read the queue and (for example send emails to users). You can add more queue consumer to manage more huge data.
Of course you will need a MQ Server.

To get a filling of asynchronous development see http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html which have good examples of Rabbit MQ ( Rabbit MQ is a opensource java base messaging service).